# Google Webservices API equivalent to the Places search box

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-geocoding-api, google-places

I like the results I get back from the example here of [Places search box](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox)
but I cannot figure which web services API and configuration would give me the same output including the partial results provided by the autocomplete. The autocomplete api does not seem to return the type of results that the search box can. It allows a lot more capability than I can find in any single web service configuration.
Is there a single endpoint I can call to replicate the same results as the search box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autocomplete and Searchbox are 2 different things, to query results as you see them in a Searchbox you must send requests to the [**Query** Autocomplete Webservice](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/query)

Comment: FINALLY! Thank you! Was banging my head against the wall, why the results were different, thanks!